# 'This' was 0xDDDDDDDD: Read Access Violation when popping a stack

Tags: c++, memory-management, stack, sfml, game-development

I am currently trying to construct the framework for a game-engine with SFML, and am learning how to utilize the Gamestate stack structure to be able to partition the code into readable pieces.

I have created a basic TestGameState class which extends an abstract class GameState, upon which other Gamestate classes will build. In my Game class, I simply create a window, run a basic game loop, and call the Gamestate update methods. The code for each class is:

**GameState.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "Game.h"

class GameState {
public: 
    Game* game = NULL;
    virtual void update() = 0;
    virtual void draw() = 0;
    virtual void handleInput() = 0;
};
```

**TestState.cpp** which is an extension of GameState class

```
#include "TestState.h"
#include "testGameplayState.h"
using namespace sf;

TestState::TestState(Game* g){
    game = g;
    texture.loadFromFile("graphics/grass.png");
    sprite.setTexture(texture);
    sprite.setPosition(Vector2f(0, 0));
}

void TestState::handleInput(){
    Event event;

    while (game->window.pollEvent(event)) {
        if (event.type == Event::KeyPressed) {
            if (event.key.code == Keyboard::O) {
                game->pushState(new TestState(game));
            }
            else if (event.key.code == Keyboard::P) {
                game->popState();
            }
        }
    }
}

void TestState::update(){}

void TestState::draw(){
    game->window.draw(sprite);
}
```

And lastly, the game object, which handles the states:
**Game.cpp**

```
#include "Game.h"
#include "GameState.h"
using namespace sf;

//Please note that states is a private stack variable.

Game::Game(){
    window.create(VideoMode(1920, 1080), "GameState Test", Style::Fullscreen);
}


Game::~Game() {
    while (!states.empty()) {
        popState();
    }
}

void Game::run() {
    while (window.isOpen()) {
        if (currentState() == nullptr) {
            std::cout << "Nullptr" << std::endl;
            window.close();
        }

        //Handle input
        currentState()->handleInput();

        //Update
        currentState()->update();

        //Draw
        window.clear();

        currentState()->draw();

        window.display();
    }
}

GameState* Game::currentState() {
    if (this->states.empty()) {
        return nullptr;
    }
    else {
        return this->states.top();
    }
}

void Game::pushState(GameState* state) {
    this->states.push(state);
}

void Game::popState() {
    delete this->states.top();
    this->states.pop();
}
```

Whenever I try creating new game state objects, I can add them to the stack and use them without issue. However, when I try to pop the current game state, it immediately exits and throws an error on the line `while (game->window.pollEvent(event))` in **TestState.cpp**, saying: `Exception thrown: read access violation. **this** was 0xDDDDDDDD.`

The 'this' in the error is presumably the Game object pointer which every state holds, because in the debugger it shows that the game object's value is 0xDDDDDDDD. I understand that 0xDDDDDDDD means that the memory being read at that address has been deleted, however, I can't figure out why this is the case. I would expect that ONLY the gamestate would be deleted, but for some reason it seems that the game pointer gets deleted as well.

I used [this](https://www.binpress.com/creating-city-building-game-with-sfml-state-manager/) and [this](http://eangogamedevelopment.blogspot.com/2016/06/part-1-creating-game-engine-state.html) as guides on how to construct my game state classes.

How might I be able to fix this issue? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What does `window.close();` do? Unless it terminates the whole program you will dereference a `nullptr` in the following lines. You also don't have any checks to prevent `popState` when `states` is empty.

Comment: How many times is `pushState` called? How many times is `popState` called? Do they match? And assuming that `GameState::states` is a `std::stack`, you should never call `top()` or `pop()` on an empty stack. You definitely need to add checks for that.

Comment: In the run loop when you pop the state the if condition currentState() == nullptr becomes true. At that point the window closes but the pointer to the current state doesn't get updated. You need to update to the next state or sleep the loop using a condition_var if necessary. In the if condition after closing the window you need to immediately break from the loop or return from the run function.

Comment: Thank you very much @OS2, your comments helped me to identify and solve the problem. I have posted again below, detailing the changes I made. I appreciate your help!

Comment: I'm sure there's still plenty of other bugs as it is the case with many problems. Suggest you also run your program in valgrind to identify other potential flaws.

Answer (score 0):

Using the tips from @OS2 and @Some programmer dude, I was able to fix the issue. After adding checks to ensure that I never operate on a null pointer, I changed the order of the method calls in my main game loop. Here is what the new loop looks like:

**Game.cpp**

```
void Game::run()
{
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        //Handle input
        currentState()->handleInput();

        //Check if there are more states
        if (currentState() == nullptr)
        {
            std::cout << "Nullptr, exiting program" << std::endl;
            window.close();

            break;
        }

        //Update
        currentState()->update();

        //Draw
        window.clear();

        currentState()->draw();

        window.display();
    }
}
```

What was occurring was that I popped the stack, which worked properly, but immediately then went on to operate on null pointers. By checking if there is a null pointer *after* I handle input, then avoid this problem.

MORE IMPORTANTLY - TO FIX THE 0xDDDDDDDD ERROR - There was only one line needed to fix the memory error.

If you pop the state via a user input, like I have above, make sure that you break out of the loop once the state has been popped. Otherwise, the while() loop will CONTINUE executing *after* the state has been terminated, and will throw the error because the state no longer exists. My edited input handling code looks like:

**TestState.cpp**

```
void TestState::handleInput()
{
    std::cout << "Handling input" << std::endl;

    Event event;

    while (game->window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == Event::KeyPressed)
        {
            if (event.key.code == Keyboard::O)
            {
                game->pushState(new TestState(game));
            }
            else if (event.key.code == Keyboard::P)
            {
                game->popState();
                
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps others who have this issue. Thank you to @OS2 and @Some programmer dude for your help in finding the problems.